# Need to turn off/disconnect WiFi on M2 Mac Mini in order to make it work

Tags: network, wifi, mac-mini

I got this M2 Mac Mini 2 months ago. New. I have a WiFi AX 160Mhz Network at home. Every time I restart this Mini, I need to either turn off WiFi and on again or disconnect/reconnect to the WiFi network in order for it to work. When I set up this computer I migrated from a laptop. I was also using Sonoma Beta for a while on it.

The symptoms are websites just loading forever and no e-mail incoming. It's just as if the network would be frozen.

Funnily enough, if the computer has not yet been entered a password but is on, it will respond to pings with a long delay (200ms even tho in the same LAN).

This is a problem as this machine needs to be reached remotely and in case of a random restart I won't be able to reach it again.

I tried deleting network plists but this didn't help.

Anyone has any idea what could be the culprit?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried forgetting and rejoining the network?  Separately, is your network meshed?

Comment: I think I did try forgetting it, but I can try again (the WPA3 Password is on iCloud too). My network is not meshed, I only have one access point.

Comment: OK great.  Please let us know by updating the question.  Also do you have any special DNS settings?  When the mini is 'frozen' can you ping numeric IP addresses as usual?  Example, google's: 142.250.80.68.  Are there other Macs on the network?  Do they exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Have you enabled any special routing rules in your router in order to enable you to reach the Mac remotely?  Port forwarding, static IP address assignment etc?  Please update question with details.

Comment: So, I tried forgetting the network again and that didn't work.

I use a Pi-Hole, but I have another M2 (a Macbook Air) that doesn't exhibit this behaviour. 

Since I use Zerotier (also tried disconnecting it and removing it, but that didn't help), I don't need any port forwarding in the router. Also no routing.

I have no clue what it can be...

Comment: Is there any way I can completely reset everything network related? Including maybe the storage of the WiFi details in the Recovery Partition. If I recall correctly I stored the details of this WiFi in the recovery Boot.